# tdengine always throws " Unable to resolve FQDN" how to solve this?

Tags: tdengine

I have tried it will occur error "DB error: Unable to resolve FQDN ". when I tied to connect taosd by ip it can connect to the db successfully. However, when query data from table. It always throws "FQDN problem".The error screen shot is below.

[image: error info]

why this happened and how to solve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When we use “taos -h” to set TDengine's FQDN to connect. We must make sure that the hostname and ip address is record in hosts file.

In your case, you connect with the TDengine server using IP, you can connect with TDengine server successfully.But the tdengine server always response with  FQDN(hostname),if this FQDN is not record in your hosts file. The client always throw error "DB error: Unable to resolve FQDN ".

so you need to configure the hosts file.